# FileUpload method for asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

net and am just wondering if there is a method for the 
file upload tag in a library anywhere ?

Thanks guys heres my code

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ForeColor="white" />
```

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and put one Upload Button and on click event of that button write code as below will do your task

Aspx page code

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fpManualCostActual" runat="server" />

   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" 
              Upload</asp:LinkButton>
```

Cs file code

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (fpManualCostActual.HasFile)
        {

                string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + 
                       SessionManager.UID.ToString() + "/MonthlyActual" + 
                       DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss") + fileExt);
                fpManualCostActual.SaveAs(filePath);

        }
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CustomException(ex, CommonHelper.ExceptionType.DBExceptionPolicy);
    }
}
```